# Any way to get all WordPress Versions dynamically ? Rest API or something?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a dynamic way to get the information about WordPress releases.
https://wordpress.org/download/releases/

Last move for me is to scrape this page on a cron but i really wanna avoid doing that.

Comment: If you just need updates, do they have an RSS feed?

Comment: They do, but not for versions specifically unfortunately 